# VBA Excel auto call module

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advence for your replay, and sorry for my english
i have a problem in my excel project
the project is to write a vba code in excel to auto send sms when a cell value change for that I used the OZEKI Excel sms client ( http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=466 )
but the problem is that client have a button (Send all)
that you must click for sending messages, but i want to do this automaticly when a cell value change my code is

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Ozeki As Workbook
    Dim FormulaRange As Range
    Dim NotSentMsg As String
    Dim MyMsg As String
    Dim SentMsg As String
    Dim MyLimit As Double

    NotSentMsg = "Normale"
    SentMsg = "Alarme"

    'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
    MyLimit = 200

    'Set the range with the Formula that you want to check
    Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("C2:C4")

    On Error GoTo EndMacro:
    For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells

        With FormulaCell

                      If .Value > MyLimit Then
                        MyMsg = SentMsg



                         If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then

                           Call Modul1.sms_send

                     End If

                  Else

                    MyMsg = NotSentMsg

                       If .Offset(0, 1).Value = SentMsg Then

                         Call Modul1.sms_send

                    End If

                 End If



            Application.EnableEvents = False
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With

    Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
    Exit Sub

EndMacro:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
         & vbLf & Err.Number _
         & vbLf & Err.Description
End Sub
```

i have add "Call Modul1.sms_send" and this code call an combobox in wich i must select the Messages.xls workbook wich containe the phones numbers and messages texte to send

But like i have already said i want to do this automaticly
the three sheets(Ozeki,Messages,formula value change) are in the same workbook

So please any idea, and thankx again

Comment: Show us the code for `sms_send`

Comment: thankx for repley Siddharth Rout

Comment: the code is to long i will write it in new answer